# Does moveit work with a skid steer robot?

Tags: moveit

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like moveit is primarily for manipulator control.  Will it work to autonomously move a skid steer robot?

Does moveit replace move_base?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55925/does-moveit-work-with-a-skid-steer-robot?/) by [virgil93](https://answers.ros.org/users/2735/virgil93/) on ROS Answers with karma: 7 on 2013-02-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) on 2013-02-22**:
I don't think so.

**Comment by [virgil93](https://answers.ros.org/users/2735/virgil93/) on 2013-02-25**:
Is that an answer to both questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

At this point we do not have move_base incorporated in moveit, but planning for ground vehicles is possible. However, this has not yet been integrated with execution of base motions.

---

Originally posted by [isucan](https://answers.ros.org/users/1805/isucan/) with karma: 1055 on 2013-03-18

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [virgil93](https://answers.ros.org/users/2735/virgil93/) on 2013-03-27**:
Thanks for the answer